# Newtonsoft Json serializer Getting NullReferenceException when using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft to serialize objects to Json with the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver Contract Resolver.

Once in while (randomly) Newtonsoft is getting a NullReferenceException, when trying to resolve contract, and then all of the rest of serialization is failing.

I'm using .Net core 2.1 on Linux machine, and Newtonsoft version 11.0.2. Contract resolver type is CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVewf.png)

```
ex=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
 at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
```

The code that serialize the object

```
if (serializerSettings == null)
    serializerSettings = new CamelCaseSerializerSettings();
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(writeTo,  DEFAULT_ENCODING, 1024*2, true))
using (var jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
{​​​​​​​
   jsonTextWriter.CloseOutput = false;
   serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, data);
}​​​​​​​
```

```
public CamelCaseSerializerSettings(Formatting serializerFormatting = Formatting.Indented, JsonConverter converter = null)
{​​​​​​​
   Formatting = serializerFormatting;
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
   if (converter != null)
   {​​​​​​​
       Converters.Add(converter);
   }​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​
```

- Why is this error happening?
- How can I fix it?

An issue was filed about this here: [Newtonsoft Json serializer Getting NullReferenceException when using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver #2507](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2507).

Comment: This looks to be a copy of [NullReferenceException when using Newtonsoft Json serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66942778/3744182) from an hour ago that was closed as a duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3744182).  If you need more specific help, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically JSON and code (as **text** not as a screen shot) that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Steve - the NullReferenceException is happening deep within Newtonsoft trying to construct a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` of some sort -- not directly within the querent's code.  So, given a proper [mcve], this might warrant an individual answer.

Comment: @Steve you didn't read the question!!!! this has nothing to do with the [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) question, and the answer there is not answering my question.

I can not reproduce the problem because it's happen on random objects.

If I had the option to reproduce the problem I had already done it and not asking for help here.

Comment: It seems  like a bug in Newtonsoft, and that why I asked the question.
Thanks for reopening.

Answer (score 2):

**This *may* be a threading bug with Newtonsoft's [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs).**  This contract resolver [shares contract information globally across all instances of the same resolver type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182), using its own inline implementation of a thread-safe dictionary caching mechanism, as can be seen in the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs#L59).  Notably, this caching mechanism differs from the [`ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L39) used elsewhere in Json.NET including [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L103).  The exception you are seeing happens when Json.NET tries to construct a new static cache from a pre-existing cache in order to add a new contract.

You may wish to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about this to Newtonsoft, the problem *might* resolve itself if `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` were to use `ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>` for caching.  E.g. the latter [uses memory barriers inside its `AddValue()` method](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L99) while the camel case resolver's inline implementation does not use memory barriers.

**As a potential workaround**, consider replacing `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` with an appropriately configured static instance of `DefaultContractResolver`:

```
static IContractResolver camelCaseResolver = new DefaultContractResolver 
{ 
    // Set ProcessDictionaryKeys and OverrideSpecifiedNames as per your preference.  These are the settings used by CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy { ProcessDictionaryKeys = true, OverrideSpecifiedNames = true } 
};

public static IContractResolver CamelCaseResolver => camelCaseResolver;

public static JsonSerializerSettings CreateCamelCaseSerializerSettings(Formatting serializerFormatting = Formatting.Indented, JsonConverter converter = null)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = CamelCaseResolver,
        Formatting = serializerFormatting,
    };
    if (converter != null)
        settings.Converters.Add(converter);
    return settings;
}
```

Newtonsoft [recommends caching the contract resolver for best performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver) so I do as well.

---

**Update**

After reviewing:

- *[Can another thread see partially created collection when using collection initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151894/3744182)*
- *[C# - The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice)*
- *[Is volatile still needed inside lock statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29544069/3744182)*

I believe there may be one or more threading bugs in [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.ResolveContract()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs#L82):

```
private static readonly object TypeContractCacheLock = new object();
private static Dictionary<StructMultiKey<Type, Type>, JsonContract>? _contractCache;

public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
{
    if (type == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    }

    // for backwards compadibility the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver shares contracts between instances
    StructMultiKey<Type, Type> key = new StructMultiKey<Type, Type>(GetType(), type);
    Dictionary<StructMultiKey<Type, Type>, JsonContract>? cache = _contractCache;
    if (cache == null || !cache.TryGetValue(key, out JsonContract contract))
    {
        contract = CreateContract(type);

        // avoid the possibility of modifying the cache dictionary while another thread is accessing it
        lock (TypeContractCacheLock)
        {
            // Bug: No checking to see whether the cache contains the contract inside the lock, which is needed in case `_contractCache` was modified by another thread between the outer check and the lock, or the value of `_contractCache` was stale.
            // Possible bug: no volatile read.
            cache = _contractCache;
            Dictionary<StructMultiKey<Type, Type>, JsonContract> updatedCache = (cache != null)
                ? new Dictionary<StructMultiKey<Type, Type>, JsonContract>(cache)
                : new Dictionary<StructMultiKey<Type, Type>, JsonContract>();
            updatedCache[key] = contract;

            // Bug: no Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            // Possible bug: no volatile write.
            _contractCache = updatedCache;
        }
    }

    return contract;
}
```

The possible bugs include:

- There is no `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before `_contractCache` is reset.  This allows the compiler to reorder the code as follows:

  ```
           _contractCache = updatedCache;
           updatedCache[key] = contract;
  ```

  Which would allow unlocked reader threads to access the `updatedCache` as it is being modified, possibly causing an exception.

  Newtonsoft's [`ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L99) does this correctly.
- There is no double check locking to see whether the required contract was added to the cache *inside the lock*.

  Once again [`ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/f7e7bd05d9280f17993500085202ff4ea150564a/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L89) does this correctly.
- *Possibly* `_contractCache` needs to be `volatile`.

  I am not sure this is necessary since it is only ever mutated from inside the `lock` statement.  It may be sufficient to add double check locking as mentioned above.

  `ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>` does *not* use `volatile` for its internal cache.

Switching to a static `DefaultContractResolver` should resolve these issues as it uses `ThreadSafeStore<TKey, TValue>` internally.

Comment: I'm not sure if a memory barrier inside the lock would solve anything. But as the non-readonly `_contractCache` field is accessed also outside of the lock, it definitely should be a volatile field.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg - Newtonsoft's `ThreadSafeStore` uses [double-checked locking](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ThreadSafeStore.cs#L90) rather than volatile (unless `ConcurrentDictionary<>` is available, which it will use in preference to any homebrew implementation.)  I think that should also work, so `DefaultContractResolver` should be fine.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg - hmm you may be correct, according to [Is volatile still needed inside lock statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29544069/3744182) (answer: **yes**).